# @Autowired not working in AuthenticationSuccessHandler of Spring-Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi I am unable to access spring bean in AuthenticationSuccessHandler of spring security.I saw many post in stackoverflow but no luck nothing works,

Spring-MVC-3.2.6
Spring Security - 3.2.0

Please find the below file for reference,

servlet-config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.taskmanagement" />
    <security:global-method-security
        pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <!--register security:expression-handler To use rights(hasPermission) along 
            wih roles(hasRole) -->
        <security:expression-handler ref="TaskManagementExpressionHandler" />
    </security:global-method-security>
    <bean id="TaskManagementExpressionHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <property name="permissionEvaluator">
            <bean id="permissionEvaluator"
                class="com.taskmanagement.security.TaskManagementPermissionEvaluator">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!--mvc:resources is used for static file location location is a folder 
        underneath spring will look for static resources 2)Also we should configure 
        this in web.xml.Because right now we configured only for .html not .pdf -->
    <mvc:resources location="pdfs" mapping="/pdfs/**" />
     <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
     <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>
    <!-- p:basename :: Here we should give the property file name here the name 
        is messages. This bean is simply used by spring for message resource -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        p:basename="messages" />
    <!--This bean is simply used by spring for message resource for locale resolver 
        it uses interceptor -->
    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"
        p:defaultLocale="en" />
    <!-- Now register locale interceptor.That's it for locale -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
            p:paramName="language"></bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
    <import resource="hibernate-config.xml" />
    <!-- Method1 Long hand <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property> <property name="suffix" 
        value=".jsp"></property> </bean> -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="3"></bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"
        p:order="2" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <map>
                                <entry key="json" value="applicaton/json"></entry>
                                <entry key="xml" value="applicaton/xml"></entry>
                            </map>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"></bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
                            <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true"></property>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="contentNegotiationManager"    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <!-- Turn off working out content type based on URL file extension, should fall back to looking at the Accept headers -->
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesviewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"></property>
    <property name="order" value="0"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Helper class to configure Tiles 2.x for the Spring Framework -->
    <!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles2/TilesConfigurer.html -->
    <!-- The actual tiles templates are in the tiles-definitions.xml -->
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/config/tiles-definitions.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean> 
<import resource="classpath:/WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml" />
</beans>
```

security-config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- We are making security as default bean instead of beans -->
    <beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- This will activate the expressions in spring valid expr are : hasRole,hasAnyRole,hasPermission,PermitAll -->
    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
        <!-- Allow login only user must have ROLE_USER -->
        <!-- The below line is for spring basic authentication without using custom 
            controller * jsp <http-basic/> -->
        <!-- For custom login use the below code -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" /> <!-- Without this it won't allow the access for login.html because in the 
            above we restrained URL with ROLE_USER -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/loginFailed.html" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout.html" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/signup.html" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/signupSubmit.html" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/session-expired.html" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/updatepassword*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/changePassword*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/403.html" access="permitAll" />
        <!--<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/> if we activate expression 
            then we should use hasRole or hasAnyRole or hasPermission or PermitAll in 
            access other wise it ill throw http status 500 failed to evaluate expr error -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login.html"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed.html" authentication-success-handler-ref="successAuthenticationHandler"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout.html" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403.html" />
        <remember-me key="myAppKey" user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
        <!-- This will prevent a user from logging in multiple times - a second login will cause the first to be invalidated. 
        Often you would prefer to prevent a second login, in which case you can use -->
         <session-management invalid-session-url="/session-expired.html">
           <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/session-expired.html"/>
         </session-management>
    </http>
    <!-- Password Hashing Bean -->
    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" >
         <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="12" />
    </beans:bean>
    <!-- After successfull login using the below handler we will map to corresponding screen -->
    <beans:bean id="successAuthenticationHandler"
        class="com.taskmanagement.authentication.handler.SuccessAuthenticationHandler"/>

    <authentication-manager>
        <!-- <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/> -->
        <authentication-provider>
            <!-- The below code will configure md5 <password-encoder hash="md5"></password-encoder> -->
            <!-- The below code will configure bcrypt -->
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"></password-encoder>
            <!--<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />  -->
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"  
    users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"  
    authorities-by-username-query="select username, authority from authorities where username =?  " />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/taskmgmt"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="username" value="root"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="password" value="root"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
<!-- Session Timeout & Concurrency control -->
</beans:beans>
```

SuccessAuthenticationHandler.java

```
package com.taskmanagement.authentication.handler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.taskmanagement.dao.CommonDao;

@Service("authenticationSuccessHandler")
public class SuccessAuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler{

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Autowired
    private CommonDao userDao;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        System.out.println("onAuthenticationSuccess::Entered");
        User user = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
        String userName = user.getUsername();
        System.out.println("userName::"+user.getUsername());
        com.taskmanagement.model.User userBo = this.userDao.get(com.taskmanagement.model.User.class,userName);
        userBo.setLastLogggedIn(new Date());
        userDao.saveOrUpdate(user);
        handle(request, response, authentication);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }
    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
              HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
                String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);

                if (response.isCommitted()) {
                    System.out.println("Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to " + targetUrl);
                    return;
                }

                redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
            }

            /** Builds the target URL according to the logic defined in the main class Javadoc. */
            protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
                boolean isUser = false;
                boolean isAdmin = false;
                Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
                for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
                    if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_USER")) {
                        isUser = true;
                        break;
                    } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                        isAdmin = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("isUser::"+isUser+"::isAdmin::"+isAdmin);
                if (isUser) {
                    return "/adminEntryAction.html";
                } else if (isAdmin) {
                    return "/addMinutes.html";
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
                }
            }

            protected void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
                if (session == null) {
                    return;
                }
                session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
            }

            public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
                this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
            }
            protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
                return redirectStrategy;
            }

}
```

In SuccessAuthenticationHandler.java while accessing this.userDao it throws nullPointerException could anyone please guide me to resolve this issue.
Kindly let me know for any queries.

CommonDao.java

```
public interface CommonDao {

    public <T> Integer save(final T obj);

    public <T> String saveRetString(final T obj);

    public <T> void delete(final Class<T> type,final String obj);

    public <T> T get(final Class<T> type, final String id);

    public <T> T merge(final T o);

    public <T> void saveOrUpdate(final T o);

    public <T> List<T> getAll(final Class<T> type);

    public List<UserBO> searchContacts(String name);
}
```

CommonDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class CommonDaoImpl implements CommonDao {
    @Autowired
    HibernateSessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Integer save(final T obj){
        //interact wth DB
     }

    public <T> String saveRetString(final T obj){
                    //interact wth DB
     }
    public <T> void delete(final Class<T> type,final String id){
                    //interact wth DB
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T get(final Class<T> type, final String id){
        return (T) hibernateSessionFactory.getSession().get(type, id);
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T merge(final T o){
                    //interact wth DB
      }

      /***/
      public <T> void saveOrUpdate(final T o){
                    //interact wth DB
      }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> List<T> getAll(final Class<T> type) {
                //interact wth DB
      }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<UserBO> searchContacts(String name) {
                    //interact wth DB
    }


}
```

web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <!-- It is need for spring security to intercept URL -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> <!-- We are going to send every rquest to this filter -->
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- It will tell where the spring security configuration xml is -->

    <!-- Bootstraps the root web application context before servlet initialization -->
    <!-- It will bootstrap our spring security -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>taskManagementServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>taskManagementServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>taskManagementServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>taskManagementServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pdfs/**</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout> <!-- THis specify timeout in minutes -->
    </session-config>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

After added the following load on startup(refer below code),

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>taskManagementServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Getting the following exception,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) ~[spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765) [catalina.jar:7.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260) [catalina.jar:7.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525) [catalina.jar:7.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515) [catalina.jar:7.0.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [na:1.6.0_18]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_18]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_18]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_18]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [na:1.6.0_18]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:140) ~[spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Aug 22, 2015 12:40:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 22 more
Aug 22, 2015 12:40:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Aug 22, 2015 12:40:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/TaskManagement] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 22, 2015 12:40:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext

Aug 22, 2015 12:40:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
```

Comment: where and how have you registerded `CommonDao` bean?

Comment: where is `DispatcherServlet` defined in XML configuration. which XML file loads first?

Comment: @Braj very good question .I attached the web.xml for your reference.

Comment: It's good to use `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` for `DispatcherServlet` to load all the configuration at startup.

Comment: @Braj Please find the updated question after i added <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> I am getting exception

Comment: Please can you try it again after removing `/WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml` context param from web.xml and importing it in `servlet-config.xml` at the bottom like `<import resource="classpath:security-config.xml" />`. Note change the `resource` attribute of import as per file location under classpath

Comment: @Braj removed security-config.xml from web.xml and imported in servlet-config.xml after that i am getting weird exception.
`13:40:32.445 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]`

Comment: what `contextConfigLocation` have you removed from your configuration file. I asked you to remove `contextConfigLocation` that is defined at top. I think you have removed `contextConfigLocation` defined under `DispatcherServlet`. By default spring looks for `applicationContext.xml` or `<name-of_dispatcher_serlvet>-servlet.xml` like in your case it will be `taskManagementServlet-servlet.xml` but if you provide `contextConfigLocation` then it overrides default context config file. you can provide all the config files separated by comma under `contextConfigLocation` param value.

Comment: Hi @Braj I removed the context-config location at the top only not the one under Dispatcher-servlet.Please find the updated post of web.xml.I am getting exception after removing the context-config location at the top only.

Comment: I think you have to do some research on spring configuration. Please read documentation on [spring mvc framework](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=spring%20mvc%20framework%20documentation)